# codeigniter renaming index.php file / Multiple application in codeigniter

Tags: apache, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have two application in my codeigniter (ver 3)
1st app (say the main app) directory is apps/main and handled by index.php in the root directory
2nd app (say api app) directory is apps/api and handled by api.php in the root directory

.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ api.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I have these rewrite rules so that I can access any URL without index.php or api.php

The main app is working fine with this rewrite rules but 2nd app (API app) is not working

when I try https://mydomain/api.php/url-slug it works fine ( it's working without rewrite rules) but when I try https://mydomain/api/url-slug it shows a 404 error. I don't know if it's a configuration error or .htaccess file error.

/apps/api/config/config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Comment: how about using a route for the api/url-slug part?

Comment: i tried it too but it doesn't work. it seems like it's rewrite rules problem.